# How can i apply to all of them (childs) a bootstrap element?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

i would like to apply this class to all childs elements

```
<div class="bg-dark">
    <div class="row mt-5">
    </div>
   <div class="row mt-5">
    </div>
   <div class="row mt-5">
    </div>
```

when i applied bg-dark those divs are not dark colors, how can i apply to all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of the first div in this example? It doesn't seem to have any characteristics other than a dark background. If that's the case, you don't need it and your code should look like this.

```
<div class="row bg-dark mt-5">
</div>
<div class="row bg-dark mt-5">
</div>
<div class="row bg-dark mt-5">
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use the outermost div as a container with height, width, border etc like so:

```
<div class="container w-full flex border">
  <div class="row bg-dark mt-5">
  </div>
  <div class="row bg-dark mt-5">
  </div>
  <div class="row bg-dark mt-5">
  </div>
</div>
```